# Get value with regex

Tags: regex, zabbix

In zabbix I'm monitoring a couple of processes that have same name but stories in different folders. So I'm trying to create discovery rule to get info about all processes with wmi. Problem is: I need get folder name from string to create correct zabbix item. Can you please help me create correct regex formula to get folders?

For example: there are 3 strings

```
%E:%test%dc1%dc.exe%
%E:%test%test2%dc2%dc.exe%
%E:%test%test2%test3%dc3%dc.exe%
```

From each string I need words

```
dc1
dc2
dc3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using % as a delimiter, this will get the second to last token in your string

```
[^%]+(?=%[^%]*%$)
```

[image]

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/3xRieN/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you're always going to have .exe files in the path, this would work fine. It matches the last text between percent signs before the file extension:

```
\%([^\%]+)\%[^\%^\.]+\Q.exe\E
```